# Python Altair: How to save figures in higher resolution

Tags: python, altair

Does anyone know how to adjust the resolution when saving figures as png or svg using the python Altair library?

The default resolution is not high enough for what I need. I've tried searching here and in the Altair docs, but can't find any info on how to set the resolution.

Comment: If you save the figure as SVG, it will have arbitrarily high resolution (because it's vector graphics, not pixel graphics)

Comment: If you absolutely need a raster, one option is to use vl2png. e.g.  `vl2png chart.json -s 2 chart.png` will output at double resolution across each axis.  See [here](https://github.com/vega/vega/pull/1234#issuecomment-379573747).  You can find the tool [here](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/blob/master/bin/vl2png)

Answer (score 4):

In Altair version 2.1 or newer, the `chart.save()` method includes an optional [`scale_factor` argument](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/saving_charts.html?highlight=chart%20html#figure-size-resolution) that can be used to adjust the size/resolution of the output.

So, to save as a PNG with 2x the default linear resolution, you can use:

```
chart.save('mychart.png', scale_factor=2.0)
```

Comment: does this also work, when you are using chart.to_json, and rendering it via vega embed? Is there anyway to increase resolution for web embedded charts?

Comment: No, this only controls the resolution for saving to file. For live-rendered plots, I believe the resolution will match your screen's resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pixels per inch (ppi) argument as follows:
`chart.save("save_path", ppi=300)`
which is similar to matplotlib's dots per inch (dpi) argument for saving figures.